# How do I merge the items of two arrays in Ruby based on the order of a third array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have three arrays.

My main list contains a mix of different entities which are verified in a DB:

```
ab = ["a:555", "b:222", "a:333", "b:777", "a:777", "a:999", "b:111"]
```

I have two more arrays of `a` and `b` entities separated, but ordered (some are missing):

```
# notice that some of the items from the initial list are missing, but the order is preserved!
a = [{id}, "a:777", "a:999"]
b = ["b:222", "b:111"]
```

What is an efficient way to merge `a` and `b` in array `c` preserving the order in `ab` where the items are present? My expected result from the procedure is:

```
c = ["a:555", "b:222", "a:777", "a:999", "b:111"]
```

I'm a Ruby newbie and everything I came up with is utterly ugly.

---

Edit:

I did know it matters, and would be confusing, but `a` and `b` are complex objects (AR) that represent the strings in `ab`.  To clarify with my code:

```
ab = ["a:555", "b:222", "a:333", "b:777", "a:777", "a:999", "b:111"]
a = [{:id => 555}, {:id => 777}, {:id => 999}]
b = [{:id => 222}, {:id => 111}]
c = []

ab.each { |item|
parts = item.split(":")
if parts[0] == "a"
  if a[0][:id].to_s() == parts[1]
    c << a.shift()
  end
else
  if b[0][:id].to_s() == parts[1]
    c << b.shift()  
  end
end

}

puts c
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not catch it. What did you come up with?

Comment: Yes the question is confusing.

Comment: Will add my code in a minute.

Comment: @Veseliq the point here is to compare the strings in `ab` with the objects in `a` and `b`. What is useful to know is how you get the strings in `ab` from your objects, I suppose you don't use the variable names `a` and `b` to produce those strings.

Comment: any chance of holding same values in both `a` and `b` or all the time they will be having unique values?

Comment: `A` and `B` values will always be unique (they are ActiveRecord objects of different models). The models have a method that can return the string from `ab` eg a.get_ab_string() will return `a:111`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the value's `id` are not distinct between a and b, one can do this

```
c = (
  a.map { |e| [ "a:#{e[:id]}", e ] } +
  b.map { |e| [ "b:#{e[:id]}", e ] }
).
sort_by { |e| ab.index(e.first) }.
map(&:last)
```

Since you now state they are distinct and that there's a method on the objects that produces your ab key, this is simpler:

```
c = (a + b).sort_by { |e| ab.index(e.get_ab_string) }
```

`ab.index` is an O(N) operation on ab, so it escalates what's ordinarily a NlnN sort to N^2.  To bring the whole solution back into O(NlnN) runtime, one can pre-calaculate the indexes of ab into a hash (an O(N) operation allowing O(1) lookups in the sort_by):

```
ab_idx = Hash[ ab.map.with_index { |e,i| [e, i] } ]
c = (a + b).sort_by { |e| ab_idx(e.get_ab_string) }
```

Comment: Last line, AWESOME. I would up this twice if I could.

Comment: @Priti Your question confuses me. `sort_by` is simpler and more efficient than your select over `any?` answer. Run complexity of sort_by is O( N lnN ); your select over any? is O( N^2 )

Comment: @dbenhur I don't to jump into any debate you know. But what I wanted to know why you used `sort_by`.as OP's output not seems to need to be sorted.

Comment: @Priti OP's question is specifically about producing an order based on the order of the keys in `ab`. sort_by allows a significantly faster algorithm -- Upon revisiting my solution I see there was overlooked runtime cost by using ab.index; so I've updated with a clause to eliminate that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basis for how to sort an array into the same order as another. Starting with two arrays:

```
ary_a = %w[one four three two]
ary_b = [1, 4, 3, 2]
```

Merge them, sort, then retrieve the one we wanted sorted:

```
ary_a.zip(ary_b).sort_by{ |a, b| b }.map(&:first)
=> ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

If we want to reverse the order:

```
ary_a.zip(ary_b).sort_by{ |a, b| -b }.map(&:first)
=> ["four", "three", "two", "one"]
```

or:

```
ary_a.zip(ary_b).sort_by{ |a, b| b }.map(&:first).reverse
=> ["four", "three", "two", "one"]
```

If there are three arrays and two need to be ordered in concert with the third:

```
ary_c = %w[a-one a-four a-three a-two]
ary_a.zip(ary_c).zip(ary_b).sort_by{ |a, b| b }.map(&:first)
=> [["one", "a-one"], ["two", "a-two"], ["three", "a-three"], ["four", "a-four"]]
```

Getting the arrays into the form needed prior to merging and sorting is the problem. Once you have those, and they have equal numbers of elements, it's a pretty simple pattern.